# Is there an easy way to multiply an array and a integer in ruby?

Tags: python, arrays, ruby

I need to repeat a certain set of items inside an array.

I need something like this in Python:

```py
["a","b"] * 3
# result: ["a","b","a","b","a","b"]
```

I tried doing the same way, but I am getting:

```
(erb):329:in `*': Array can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)
```

Is there an easy way to solve it?

Edit: Already solved. It seems to happen that it works when it is done like this

```rb
["a", "b"] * 2
```

But does not work backwards:

```rb
2 * ["a", "b"]
```

Comment: If you need this in Python, you might want to tag it accordingly.

Comment: You need it in Python, or is that a Python example?

Comment: What result did you get when it did not work?

Comment: "I tried doing **the same way**" - the error message indicates otherwise.

Comment: I think the issue you're experiencing is because when you do `array * integer` you're calling the array version of the `*` method which knows what to do with a an integer, but when you do the opposite and do `integer * array` the integer version of `*` doesn't know what to do with an array. Also if you find an answer to your question, post it as an answer, don't edit your original question with the answer

Comment: Remember that just because an operator is commutative in mathematics doesn't mean that it will be in Ruby. `a * b` is really just `a.*(b)` after all and that could be very different from `b.*(a)`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it works in my Ruby 2.5:

```
["a","b"] * 3
# => ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
```

> `ary * int → new_ary`
>
> Repetition — (...) returns a new array built by concatenating the int copies of self.
>   [Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-2A)

Answer (score 2):

## A * B is not always B * A

`3 * 4` means:

> `3` repeated `4` times.

`4 * 3` means:

> `4` repeated `3` times.

`["a", "b"] * 3` means:

> `["a", "b"]` repeated `3` times.

But what would

> `3` repeated `["a", "b"]` times.

mean? How can you do anything `["a", "b"]` times?

## In Python

In Python, both are allowed:

```
["a","b"] * 3
3 * ["a","b"]
```

and return:

```
['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

but the second looks sloppy IMHO.

Comment: Are you sure about the Python? `["a","b"] * 3` does the same thing in Ruby and Python, no?

Comment: @muistooshort: Indeed, not enough coffee on that day! That's not the point I wanted to make. I really like Python list comprehensions and want to use them even when they're not needed. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I only noticed because I recently gave myself a crash course in Python to get around Ruby's somewhat abysmal start up times for scripts. I hear you on the list comprehensions in any case.

Comment: @muistooshort It's definitely worth it. If you didn't already, you could install Anaconda and play with numpy, sympy, pandas, keras, networkx and pygame. It's great to be able to use so many powerful libraries with just a few lines of code. I'll always love Ruby but the Python ecosystem sure is impressive.